# How can i remove index.php in url?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i remove index.php from `url` in codeingnator.

I have changed in config page from `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'` 
to 
`$config['index_page'] = ''.`

But I dont know ,where i can add .htaccess file?

Comment: It means that you want to add default page

Comment: I want to add inside application folder or inside codeingnator folder? @Ibnelaiq

Comment: root of your application you will find .htaccess file edit it and add lines below

Answer (score 2):

**Need to change config file :**
`'$config['base_url'] = ''; 
$config['index_page'] = '';`

**htaccess file :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
#RewriteBase /     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Re-write htaccess file with the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

you could found more information [Here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Answer (score 1):

add this lines to .htaccess file

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

[check codeigniter documention](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)